# How to redirect certain website on my wifi network?

Tags: router, dns

I am trying to find a way so that on my wifi network I can restrict the access of site like facebook I can do this using parental control . Is there any way so that I can redirect to certain host or IP address with message . I need to do it without changing host file I want do do this from my network . Everyone in my network when open the site facebook it should go to google or something else is it possible .

Comment: Sounds very dangerous to me and you may not get to much detail because what you're after could also be used for the power of EVIL

Comment: You can't, because Facebook uses SSL and you would have to use forged or locally installed certificates to redirect it.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way:

Run a DNS and supply router with your DNS IP. Edit DNS tables.

or

Run a proxy that allows redirects.

or

Run a firewall (like your parental control).

Comment: do you have any other example